# GenerateEntities from Database using NetBeans JPA extra "entityPK" classes?

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, primary-key, entities

So i'm trying to generate entities directly from my database, using *netbeans* but
Im having a hard time here using the option `New -> "Entity Class from Database"`.

For each entity that has a foreign key associated with it. it Creates an extra entity called "`EntityPK`"

For example, I have a "`Patient`" entity that has an ID and "`CampusID`" from the entity "`Campus`"

When I use the generator, it automatically generates a `Patient` Entity, and also a `PatientPK` Entity, that stores both ids.

Is that normal? I'm getting a lot of errors when trying to use `EntityManager`, So i'm thinking that may be the problem.

Comment: (This isn't really an answer, so I'm not posting it as such.) If the entity-generating wizard isn't doing the job, just write the entity classes by hand. It'll probably be faster than trying to make NetBeans do it correctly.

Comment: Thats too bad though, I have a lot of entites on my db. But thanks anyway for the advice and edit!

Comment: Weird. I just tried to reproduce it but it did't happen. Postgresql jdk8 netbeans 8.1. May be some constraints has influence. Need schema to see relation between patient and campus tables

Comment: But what i think is netbeans didn't know best about all constraints in database that is why some operations impossible on database level and netbeans knows nothing about it.

Comment: Errors might be a reason of incorrect using operation sequence. For example, if u will try to remove campus record (with id=1) which is still referred in some of patient, u will get constraint error. U have to find all patients that has reference to this campus (campus_id=1) remove(set null) campus reference (or set another if it is marked as not null) or delete those patients and only after that remove campus itself. It can be managed using cascade annotation (Netbeans didn't generate those when i tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this solved it for me. 
Instead of using the regular @JoinColumn to establish the Many to One Relationship, I changed it to @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.

And I refactored  the code myself, and removed the extra PKEntities.